# How to execute a flume configuration file using java program?

Tags: java, flume

I have a flume configuration file `filename.conf`, when i execute this file in terminal it works well. But I am trying trying to excute the same file in java program using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` function it not works.

This is my `flume` execution command :

```
/home/path/flume/bin/flume-ng agent --conf-file /home/path/flume/filename.conf --name Agent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

This is my java code:

```
Process p;

p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/path/flume/bin/flume-ng agent --conf-file   /home/path/flume/filename.conf --name TwitterAgent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console");

p.waitFor();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

String line = "";

while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) 
{
System.out.println(line);
}
```

I am not getting any error.

Comment: share your java code and error messages...

Comment: Process p;
 p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/path/flume/bin/flume-ng agent --conf-file /home/path/flume/filename.conf --name TwitterAgent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console");
 p.waitFor();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
 String line = "";
 while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
 System.out.println(line);
}

I am not getting any error. But it not works.

Comment: better to add this to question as an edit.

Comment: I edited my post... Thanks for your response... can you tell me the suggesion to solve this problem

Comment: use p.exitValue() to see what is exit value of the command. what do the command?

Comment: i used p.exitValue(); i am getting "process hasn't exited" exception...

Answer (score 1):

Flume provides an Application class to run the conf file using a Java program. Please find the below program.

```
import org.apache.flume.node.Application;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

public class flume {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] args1 = new String[] { "agent","-nTwitterAgent","-fflume.conf" };
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        Application.main(args1);
        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "/");
   }
}
```

In the Application class you need provide your agent, agentname and the flume.conf file path. Here in my case flume.conf file is in my project classpath only so i have just specified as -fflume.conf. If it is in a different directory you need to specify the full path there. After this you can run it as a normal java program itself.

Comment: You can also use fileutils to provide your keywords dynamically to flume.conf file.